# MySQL ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY error despite not having ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY enabled

Tags: python, mysql, google-cloud-platform

I've recently migrated a MySQL database from local to Google Cloud Platform in preparation for deployment. When I first did this, I encountered:

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1055, "Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'testing.Event.EventID' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by")
```

Annoying, but no problem: a quick search revealed it could be turned off in the tags section of the GCP console, and that seemed to be OK as I wasn't too worried about the risks of turning it off. This worked, or so I thought. The same issue continues to appear days after setting the "Traditional" tag on my GCP SQL instance.

Even when I run the query:

```
SELECT @@sql_mode;
```

The result I get is:

```
STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,TRADITIONAL,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Which does not contain the only_full_group_by setting, and nonetheless I receive the error: `this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Is there some reason that this error would continue to appear despite not being in the setting that the error code says causes the error?

Comment: or you could just fix your query

Comment: @danblack appreciate your response. I could certainly do that, but in some ways feels like the easy way out in an error I know shouldn't occur, no?

Comment: the query could be giving misleading results because of the aggregation. Normally they are fairly easy to change. Do you want to show the query by editing the question, include table structure and we'll see if we can help out making it full_group_by compliant.

Comment: a) do you run your query directly or is it part of a stored procedure? They can have different sql modes b) Disabling only_full_group_by is actually the easy way out: MySQL allowed an ambiguous syntax that is forbidden by the sql standard and that no other database system uses. Since MySQL 5.7, MySQL changed to the proper behaviour, but allowed (for compatibility with older code) to disable that (correct sql standard) behaviour again. So fixing your code certainly isn't "an easy way out", but the proper way to handle it, if you have the time to do and test it.